# MacOs BLE "unsupported descriptor"

Tags: macos, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an application for MacOs using Qt 5.15.2 clang 64bit on a Mac mini with macOS Big Sur 11.1.

I'm trying to run the Heart Rate Server Example ([link to the page of the example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-heartrate-server-example.html)) but I'm having some problem. When I run the application with the debugger I get the following application output:

```
2021-07-22 16:22:03.774769+0200 heartrate-server[43797:13434312] [qt.bluetooth.osx] unsupported descriptor "{00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}"
2021-07-22 16:22:03.775480+0200 heartrate-server[43797:13434385] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: <CBPeripheralManager: 0x100a17a80> has no restore identifier but the delegate implements the peripheralManager:willRestoreState: method. Restoring will not be supported
2021-07-22 16:22:04.831350+0200 heartrate-server[43797:13434385] [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBPeripheralManager: 0x100a17a80> can only accept this command while in the powered on state
```

What should I do to fix the unsupported descriptor error? And what should I do to remove the "can only accept this command while in the powered on state"? I found that the problem for this second sentence is that I'm calling startAdvertising to early, I should wait that the powered state is actually on, but I did not find a way to wait for this state at the moment. Does anybody have an idea?

P.s: I set the "Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description" into the Info.plist file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you turn on your Bluetooth ? because this app needs it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R yes, the bluetooth is active.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not intimately familiar with Bluetooth Low Energy terminology, [this article](https://academy.nordicsemi.com/courses/bluetooth-low-energy-fundamentals/lessons/lesson-4-bluetooth-le-data-exchange/topic/services-and-characteristics/) provides a very solid overview.

`00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` is the client characteristic configuration descriptor (CCCD). It's a special descriptor that allows a connecting party to request notifications for a particular characteristic.

The Qt example from your question adds CCCD to the heart rate measurement characteristic [on line 94](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtconnectivity.git/tree/examples/bluetooth/heartrate-server/main.cpp?h=5.15#n94).

On Apple platforms, Qt (presumably) uses the [Core Bluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth). In Core Bluetooth, you cannot manually set the CCCD on a characteristic. The framework abstracts away this concept and provides higher-level primitives for notifications.

I'm not sure whether this is a fundamental abstraction mismatch of QtBluetooth or whether it's just the example that is wrong.